# Failed to instantiate abstract superclass 'ClassName' using public constructor with arguments - Mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have this code

```
@Document(collection = "document1")
@Getter
@ToString
public abstract class DocumentA {
   private String name;
   private String lName;

   public DocumentA(){}

}


@lombok.Getter
public class DocumentB extends DocumentA {
   private String someFields;
   public DocumentB() {}
}
```

I get this error when I do mongoRepository.findById(). My repository method looks like this

```
DocumentA findById(String id);
```

This repository method is expected to return DocumentB object.

Same code is working with Spring-boot 2.1.5 version. I upgraded version to 2.6.1 and started facing this issue.

Can you see where is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I actually don't see how this could actually work in 2.1.5. You have only a no arg constructor with no setters so it should not be able to get any data. Have you tried adding `@Setter` and/or `@AllArgsContructor`?

Comment: Yes grekier. I added @Setter on baseclass and superclass. Still facing the same issue.
I see some changes in spring-data-commons in how objects are instantiated/deserialized in 2.6.1 compared to 2.1.5.